# Problems rendering on a galaxy tab GT-P1000

Tags: android, opengl-es, galaxy-tab

Hi have a problem running my software on the samsung  galaxy tab.
Sometimes (but not always!) areas that are rendered transparent look garbled. I have attached an image showing a screen capture done on the device, which looks perfect for a strange reason, and a photo that shows the garbled half transpaent black box.

Has somebody an explanation for this effect or can somebody point me in a direction  - I really don't know where I should start searching since the same software runs flawless on a galaxy s2 and on all IOS devices.

Perhaps somebody here has seen somthing similar and knows reasons that might lead to artifacts like these.

[screenshot vs photo http://www.applab.at/img/garbage_samsung_tab7.png](http://www.applab.at/img/garbage_samsung_tab7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the device itself.
Sometimes if you turn the device on, you see a garbled screen befoer the samsung logo appears. Then this effect shows whenever running the software.
If the device boots without a garbled screen, everything is fine.